# How to change Stackblitz Jasmine configuration for Angular testing to set "random: false"

Tags: angular, jasmine, stackblitz

When making a Stackblitz project for Angular testing, there is no way I have found to change the default Jasmine setting of "run tests in random order".  Of course I can click on the OPTIONS box and change it manually, but I would like to create projects with a different default.

The Jasmine docs ([here](https://jasmine.github.io/setup/nodejs.html)) show a number of ways to configure this, but none of them appear to work in Stackblitz.  For example, adding the code:

```
jasmine.loadConfig({
    random: false
});
```

Produces an error if added to any of the configuration files (for example `main.ts`) as follows:

```
Error in /~/main.ts (30:5)
jasmine.loadConfig is not a function
```

Those same docs also talk about editing the file in node_modules, but of course there is no way of getting to that in Stackblitz (that I know of).

Here is a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-q-53204907?file=main.ts) to show what I mean.  Notice the tests are run in random order.  :)

Has anyone managed to make this work?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is dedicated [configure](https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/Env#configuration) method on Jasmine environment:

**main.ts**

```
jasmine.getEnv().configure({random: false}); // add this
bootstrap();
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-q-53204907-wf9vgn?file=main.ts)**

Comment: Very nice!  How did you know to use `jasmine.getEnv()` that way?